# Reshaping/Transforming Pandas dataframe from pivoted table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pivoted dataframe with customer recommendations that looks like the following:

[image]

I want to reshape this dataframe or form another new dataframe containing *CustomerID* column and 4 new additional columns called *'Recommendation#1','Recommendation#2','Recommendation#3' and 'Recommendation#4'*, where each column will have the top 4 highest scored items for each customer. I am trying to make it look something like this:

[image]

However I am a bit lost in how to approach this in python to obtain my wanted dataframe from my pivoted dataframe. Any help or suggestions on how to approach this would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) and keep the highest `n` elements in each row:

```
n=4
data = df.values.argsort().T[::-1].T[:,:n]
```

And build a dataframe from the obtained array, and columns that you specify:

```
columns = ['Recommendation#{}'.format(i) for i in range(1,data.shape[1]+1)]
df = pd.DataFrame(df.columns[data], columns=columns, index = df.index) 
print(df)

         Recommendation#1 Recommendation#2 Recommendation#3 Recommendation#4
ID1            Item4            Item2            Item8            Item6
ID2            Item5            Item1            Item4            Item6
ID3            Item7            Item6            Item8            Item3
```

Comment: Hi @nixon thanks for the suggestion, but instead of hard-coding the word 'Item', would there be a way to get the original column name like 'Item1','Item4'... and pass that as the Recommendations columns value instead of the column index as it is with your  df.applymap(lambda x: 'Item'+str(x)) results?

Comment: Okay @user3116949 it actually turned out much simpler changing it to fit your suggestion :)

Comment: Yes @ALollz I do use `df.columns[data] `in the dataframe constructor to get the column names, thx for suggesting

Answer (score 0):

First the get the dataframe `values`, then sort them with `numpy.sort`, reverse the order and get the 4 first entries. Then set this data into a new dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'I1':[0,5,0],'I2':[5,0,0],'I3':[1.2,0,3],'I4':[5,4,0],'I5':[2,5,0],'I6':[3,3,5],'I7':[0,0,5],'I8':[3,0,4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
#    I1  I2   I3  I4  I5  I6  I7  I8
# 0   0   5  1.2   5   2   3   0   3
# 1   5   0  0.0   4   5   3   0   0
# 2   0   0  3.0   0   0   5   5   4
a = df.values
a = a.argsort(axis=1)
a = a[:,::-1][:,:4]+1
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Rec1', 'Rec2', 'Rec3', 'Rec4'], data=a)
df2[list(df2)] = 'I' + df2[list(df2)].astype(str)
print(df2)
#   Rec1 Rec2 Rec3 Rec4
# 0   I4   I2   I8   I6
# 1   I5   I1   I4   I6
# 2   I7   I6   I8   I3
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'CustomerID':['ID1','ID2','ID3'],
                   'Item1':[0,5,0],
                   'Item2':[5,0,0],
                   'Item3':[1.2,0,3],
                   'Item4':[5,4,0],
                   'Item5':[2,5,0],
                   'Item6':[3,3,5],
                   'Item7':[0,0,5],
                   'Item8':[3,0,4]})

df.set_index('CustomerID', inplace=True)
df = df * -1
df2 = df.apply(np.sort, axis=1)
df2 = abs(df2)
```

Output

```
    CustomerID
ID1    [5.0, 5.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.2, 0.0, 0.0]
ID2    [5.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
ID3    [5.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: It need the index of the recommendation, not the value.